# What is the mathematical meaning of swap high part and low part of a uint64_t?

Tags: c, hash, bit-manipulation, sha256

The code is from an open source project of [sha256](https://github.com/noryb009/sha256),

```
uint64_t swapE64(uint64_t val) {
    uint64_t x = val;
    x = (x & 0xffffffff00000000) >> 32 | (x & 0x00000000ffffffff) << 32;
    x = (x & 0xffff0000ffff0000) >> 16 | (x & 0x0000ffff0000ffff) << 16;
    x = (x & 0xff00ff00ff00ff00) >>  8 | (x & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ff) <<  8;
    return x;
}
```

the function is not complex, but I don't know its mathematical means and usage.

---

My fault, I did't ask the question very clear. In different environments which use different endian representation, it is clear, this function will keep the data in a same meaning, but under the same endian representation, what does it means?

It absolutely will change the meaning of the data, or there is some other reason to swap it?

Comment: Read the specification for sha256, and all will be clear to you. This is, basically, swapping the endianness of an int64.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I've read some other implementation of sha256 from github, but there is no such function.

Comment: A good answer to this question requires knowing if you understand how to represent numbers in binary. Also, do you know what endianness means?

Comment: @asimes, I know it's swap the bytes and switch between little endian and big endian. If it is under different environment which use different endian representation, I can understand, but in the same environment, I can't.

Comment: Imagine that you implementing code for a protocol that is strictly little endian. It is possible to write code which is portable by first detecting what the endianness of the machine you are using is and then conditionally applying this function if you are on a big endian machine. The mathematical implications of swapping endiannes from little to big on a machine that was little to begin with makes very little sense, the numbers would appear to just be garbage when interpreted in decimal

Comment: You may ask yourself the same question in decimals: what's the mathematical meaning of reversing a number's digits? That is, e.g. changing from 18374 to 47381? As far as I know, there is no mathematical meaning, other than some congruence relations (e.g. the two numbers are congruent mod 9).

Comment: ?siht ekil sdrawkcab gnitirw fo gninaem citsiugnil eht s'tahW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Pseudocode) for SHA256  on wikipedia it says

> Pre-processing: append the bit '1' to the message append k bits '0',
>   where k is the minimum number >= 0 such that the resulting message
>       length (modulo 512 in bits) is 448. **append length of message (without the '1' bit or padding), in bits, as 64-bit big-endian
>   integer**
>       (this will make the entire post-processed length a multiple of 512 bits)

x86/x86_64 Linux and Unix are small endian.

It's converting the length of the message to big endian to add it to the end of the message, which it does in the source at L105 of sha256.c, and that section of the code is the only place where the `swapE64` function is called:

https://github.com/noryb009/sha256/blob/77a185c837417ea3fc502289215738766a8f8046/sha256.c#L100